# How to draw multiple CALayer sublayers from parent layer

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics, calayer

I have a CALayer with two subLayers that contain semi-static content.  While rendering the top layer I would like to occasionally just go ahead and render the sublayers without scheduling an update with setNeedsDisplay.

I know that one option is to create delegate classes and implement `drawLayer:inContext:` but I wanted to render the sublayers immediately perhaps with renderInContext: but I don't want to render into the parent layer.

Is there a way I can switch or obtain the context of the sublayers to do immediate drawing into them?

Comment: Why do you want to draw into the layer context immediately? Either you draw into your own context (like an image context) or you update the layer until the next screen update (by calling setNeedsDisplay)…

Comment: I'm utilizing an existing architecture that expects to draw to a series of layers and depending on the data, will skip certain layers.  If I utilize setNeedsDisplay I have to cache all of the config for that layer for later access when it updates.  I can do this of course but was hoping it was easy to just draw to another layer as needed.

Comment: From what I understand you would like to use a bunch of layers as empty canvases for your drawing and you don't want any of the layers to hold on to state information including the top-level layer. CALayers are not meant to be used as such. CALayers are expected to draw themselves or have some delegate do the work. Which ever does the drawing should hold the necessary state information.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'm OK for the top level layer to hold onto state, especially if that would allow me to draw into sublayers based on that state.  Is there a layer mechanism that can do this?  Can GL layers be drawn this way?  If not, please make your comment the answer.  If that's the case I'll just need to have shared state between the layers so the delegates can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism for doing the drawing while holding on to the state in a "root" object is to set the root object as the delegate for any layer for which it will do the rendering. Then you should implement drawLayer:inContext: in the delegate.

Note that a layer will not require redrawing unless you ask it to with setNeedsDisplay. So in your case, would would loop through your state and call `[layer setNeedsDisplay]` only those layers that need it and in turn only those layers will call drawLayer:inContext:.